# Office 365 Management API: Filter using StartTime and EndTime does not work

Tags: sharepoint-online, office365api

I am trying to fetch the audit logs of SharePoint tenant for a certain time period (suppose for half an hour today earlier) but if use startTime and endTime filter it doesn't work. It always shows me content from around 24 hours ago which is not useful. Isn't this API useless if any filter does not work?

Sample URL I have used in the script:

"https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/$tenant/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint&startTime=2020-02-12T23:00&endTime=2020-02-12T23:15"

No matter what timestamp I put data is always around 24 hours before. Did anybody encounter it before? Is there any resolution for that? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay looks like you can only get logs older than 24 hours. If you put a timestamp less than 24 hours old, it just provides you the latest log, and ignores the timestamp.